# How to automate adding xml tags to plain text document

Tags: xml

I'm looking for a way to automatically add XML tags to plain text documents.  I'll be creating some customized tags (rather than just formatting).  Is there existing software that does this?  Or can someone refer me to a website that discusses the process?  (Sorry, I know this is vague, but I've got to start somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any services available as such. If you would like to code it on your own, you may have to use Elements, subelements and it's values there should be a business logic to differentiate child and parent elements. 
Consider all values,tags are available in a .txt file.
In python you can get this file and use some XML libraries to build an XML by reading the values in the file one by one.

Comment: use a JSON format to dynamically get data and read the JSON file checking whether any parent node has child objects. This is a way to reuse the XML file generation.

Answer (score -1):

Try using XML Linq like code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
               "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
               "<dataroot>" +
                 "<Op>" +
                   "<Where>AIX</Where>" +
                   "<Amount>24</Amount>" +
                 "</Op>" +
                 "<Op>" +
                   "<Where>LILLE</Where>" +
                   "<Amount>10</Amount>" +
                 "</Op>" +
                 "<Op>" +
                   "<Where>LILLE</Where>" +
                   "<Amount>18</Amount>" +
                 "</Op>" +
                 "<Op>" +
                   "<Where>AIX</Where>" +
                   "<Amount>20</Amount>" +
                 "</Op>" +
                 "<Op>" +
                   "<Where>LILLE</Where>" +
                   "<Amount>12</Amount>" +
                  "</Op>" +
               "</dataroot>";

            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse(input);
            var groups = doc1.Descendants("Op").GroupBy(x => x.Element("Where").Value).ToList();
            int count = doc1.Descendants("Op").Count();
            int total = doc1.Descendants("Amount").Select(x => (int)x).Sum();

            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Document></Document>");
            XElement document = doc2.Element("Document");
            XElement recap = new XElement("Recap");
            document.Add(recap);
            recap.Add(new XElement("Nop", count));
            recap.Add(new XElement("TotAmount", total));

            foreach (var opGroup in groups.AsEnumerable())
            {
                XElement location = new XElement("Location");
                document.Add(location);
                location.Add(opGroup.Elements("Where").FirstOrDefault());
                int groupCount = opGroup.Count();
                int locAmount = opGroup.Descendants("Amount").Select(x => (int)x).Sum();
                location.Add(new XElement("Nop", groupCount));
                location.Add(new XElement("LocAmount", locAmount));

                XElement ops = new XElement("Ops");
                location.Add(ops);
                foreach (var op in opGroup)
                {
                    ops.Add(op.Element("Amount"));
                }

            }


        }
    }
}
​
```